# Разрешить комментарии для конкретного пользователя в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, комментарии

Здраствуйте. 
Как мне Разрешить комментарии для конкретного пользователя в Wordpress. Наподобии выбора роли. До того как он ещё сделал 1-й комментарий.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрел известные плагины управления ролями и возможностями пользователя - не увидел такого.

Ладно, залез в код ядра. За логику этого вопроса отвечает код в файле `/wp-includes/comment.php`.

```
if ( 1 == get_option('comment_whitelist')) {
    if ( 'trackback' != $comment_type && 'pingback' != $comment_type && $author != '' && $email != '' ) {
        $comment_user = get_user_by( 'email', wp_unslash( $email ) );
        if ( ! empty( $comment_user->ID ) ) {
            $ok_to_comment = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT comment_approved FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE user_id = %d AND comment_approved = '1' LIMIT 1", $comment_user->ID ) );
        } else {
            // expected_slashed ($author, $email)
            $ok_to_comment = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT comment_approved FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_author = %s AND comment_author_email = %s and comment_approved = '1' LIMIT 1", $author, $email ) );
        }
        if ( ( 1 == $ok_to_comment ) &&
            ( empty($mod_keys) || false === strpos( $email, $mod_keys) ) )
                return true;
        else
            return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Здесь всего 15 строк, и в них нет вызова ни действий, ни фильтров. Т.е. модифицировать принятие решения по этому вопросу без изменения кода ядра не представляется возможным. Но править ядро - чревато и правка проживёт лишь до следующего обновления WordPress.

Придумайте какой-то другой подход, который бы вас устроил.